# Cartesian products of power sets problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having problem with understanding power set products of cartesian sets.

I know that power set $P(X)$ holds $2^n$ elements, where n is amount of elements in X.

The problem is following:

Let $A= \{ \{a\}, \{b\}  \}$

and $B = \{ \{ a,b\}, \emptyset\}$

Find $P(A) \times P(B)$ and $P(A \times B)$.

I found $P(A) = $ $\{ \emptyset, \{ \{ a\} \}, \{ \{ b\} \},\{ \{ a\}, \{ b\} \}  \} $

Not sure if $B = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset\} , \{ \{ a\},\{ b\} \} ,\{ \{ a, b\} \}  \} $

or $B = $ $\{ \emptyset, \{ \{ a\}\},\{\{ b\} \} ,\{ \{ a, b\} \}  \}$ ?

*Edit:*

$B = $ $\{ \emptyset, \{ \{ a\}\},\{\{ b\} \} ,\{\emptyset, \{ a, b\} \}  \}$,

*Edit2:*

$B = $ $\{ \emptyset,\{ \emptyset \} , \{\{ a, b\} \},\{\emptyset, \{ a, b\} \}  \}$
That is clear.

How to find cartesian products $P(A) \times P(B)$ and $P(A \times B)$ ?

*Edit3:* Okay, Cartesian product of $P(A) \times P(B)$ contatins 10 elements, because by adding together all products, empty set appears 7 times.

Comment: NO: $P(B) = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{ \{ a,b \} \}, \{ \{ a,b \}, \emptyset \} \}$.

Comment: The rule is the same: the emptyset (always), the "full set" (always).

Comment: Yes of coruse !

Answer (score 0):

I think powerset B should be:
={●,{●},{{a,b}},{{a,b},●}}
As powerset is set of subsets of set as elements. (●- here phi empty set )